# Track Pixel Coordinates in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to build a Vt of 360 degree panopictures with OSM map using Leaflet.
I need a function which returns the pixel coordinates of a point/marker relative to the origin pixel (to the top left corner of the map container) when moving (i.e panning/dragging) the map and when zooming the map.

Any suggestions/hints?

Answer (score 1):

From the Leaflet API:

```
// @method containerPointToLayerPoint(point: Point): Point
// Given a pixel coordinate relative to the map container, returns the corresponding
// pixel coordinate relative to the [origin pixel](#map-getpixelorigin).

containerPointToLayerPoint: function (point) {
   return toPoint(point).subtract(this._getMapPanePos());
},
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you @sasha-dev. Perhaps latLngToContainerPoint(<LatLng> latlng) which returns a point with Latlng input.  I need a x, y coord relative to the origin pixel when panning/zooming/dragging the map.  I have almost no competence in JS and I can hardly understand even very basic simple stuff: var x = ..... ; var y=.....;  Could you provide the code lines? Thank you in advance. Giuseppe

Comment: @guiseppe ok I think what you want to use is `project`. If the pixel origin is `map.getPixelOrigin()`, the pixel coordinates of items on the map relative to that can be calculated with `map.project(latLng)`.

Comment: This method can account for zoom as well by just passing it a zoom parameter:
`map.project(latLng, map.getZoom())`

Panning/dragging the map actually does not update the origin pixel! It is only updated on zoom. In order to update it after panning without having to change the zoom - you would want to calculate the maps new topleft manually:

```JS
var topLeft = this._getNewPixelOrigin(map.getCenter(), map.getZoom());
```

and call

```JS
map.project(latLng, map.getZoom())._subtract(topLeft);
```

Comment: I use this to debug pixel origin concepts for my leaflet plugin:
https://sasha.mapknitter.org/debug/pixelorigin.html

Comment: @ sasha-dev, thank you. Yes I tried that way too. Actually  latLngToContainerPoint(<LatLng> latlng) works, i.e. it returns the x,y coord , with map.on 'move' for panning/dragging and zooming as well.